# How do I get the remote ip address with httpurlconnection

Tags: java, http

I'm connecting to a url with a httpurlconnection in java 1.6

The  server I connect uses DNS round robin to share load between multiple servers.

How can I get the remote ip address that I have actually connected to?

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//I then need something like this!
log(SUCCESS, "made connection to: " + urlConn.getRemoteIp());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://yahoo.com");
String host = url.getHost();
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
String ip = address.getHostAddress();
```

Comment: And this might give the right IP since the jvm caches DNS queries, unless that is disabled on the jvm

Comment: nos is right: if you've disabled the default behavior of permanent DNS record caching in the JVM, this approach could return imprecise results.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, but since the JVM is caching DNS lookups, you can use InetAddress.getByName(serverName) to find the actual IP address being used unless you've set the system property "networkaddress.cache.ttl" to disable the cache.